# Git error when uninstall and installing Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew

So I uninstalled Homebrew from my computer for some reasons using a Ruby command, which said "This will uninstall all packages installed with Brew". I did this and now when I try to install Homebrew again, I get a Git error saying "Please make sure you have correct Access Rights".

I assumed this error was because uninstalling Brew uninstalled Git, but when I type "git --version" I get "git version 2.15.0" so that isn't the issue.

I then generated a new SSH key, and added the public key to my git account. Doing

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Gives me

```
Hi {{username}}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

Even when I try to git clone my own repo, I get the same error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is log of the Brew install

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown rafaykalim /usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/chgrp admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force
```

I also manually removed the /usr/local/Homebrew. This is the command to uninstall Brew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

EDIT: I just uninstalled git from my computer, and I am still getting the same error. Have no idea what is going on!

I used this script to uninstall Git:
https://gist.github.com/naomik/11245234

Comment: You should use the official Homebrew uninstall script rather than some random 5-years-old script.

Comment: I don't think this has anything todo with homebrew. Most likely this is a problem regarding to SSH and authentication. Perhaps you have added an incorrect key or you could run `git clone` as another user (e.g using another key), the repository does not exists or you don't have access to it, the possibilities is endless.